# Best Arduino board to play sound

Tags: audio

I'm looking to purchase an Arduino for a little robot I'm going to make.  The reason I've chosen Arduino is because it's much easier to use with servos and LEDs than a Raspberry Pi, but a nice little touch would be to have it play some sounds (voice recordings and mechanical SFX).  I was just wondering (now I'm not after opinions here, but looking more at how each of the boards have been designed) what the *best* Arduino board for playing sound is, or if they are all pretty much the same in this regard.

(Note 'pins' was the best tag I could find for this post for lack of a 'sound' or 'speakers' one.  If you want to edit it to something more appropriate please do)

Comment: (Sorry, I can't add this as a comment) If you're looking for a good audio processing chip then I would recommend you the **VLSI VS1003** chip. It costs **$2.30** (standalone) or $7 as a module (on eBay today) and it's able to play **MP3** (even VBR), **WMA, WAV** (ADPCM) and even **MIDI**. Also it **can record sound** from mic or line in and encode it as ADPCM WAV. Supports streaming and has other powerful features, like filters and bass boost and is well documented (see the [datasheet](http://www.vlsi.fi/fileadmin/datasheets/vs1003.pdf)). You would need some data source for it, so either a st

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need is to play back lo-fi audio then any with PWM will do, which means that any Arduino will do. If you want hi-fi sound then you'll need a DAC, which means either choosing the Due or using a discrete DAC via SPI. If you need decoding of complex audio formats such as MP3 or Vorbis then you'll need either the Due for its power, or a separate audio playback shield that supports the formats you're interested in.

Comment: I believe Due had proper DAC's. It also has a fair bit more muscle to do some processing besides playing the sound.

Comment: The Due has dual 12-bit DACs, and runs a 32-bit ARM core at 84MHz versus the 8-bit AVR core at 16MHz of most other Arduinos.